# TV-Butler USB DVB-C Stick not visible visible via /dev/dvb

Tags: usb, dvb

I bought 2x TV-Butler DVB-C Sticks (along with a DVBLOGIC License) a few years ago. Because DVBLogic is now out of business I try to configure them via TVHeadend (installed via snap store) on a Ubuntu 22.04 Virtual machine

Unfortunaltely TVHeadend doesn't recognize the card. It is not visible via /dev/dvb
Because TVHeadend has an option to set an alternative path where to find DVB devices I'd like to ask if there is such a path available or a way how to create /dev/dvb based on other information.

The Sticks are recognized and work fine on a different system (QNAP NAS) using the old DVB-Logic Software.

Note: the VM detects the 2 DVB-C sticks as devices form Dexatek Technology Ltd. Vendor[image]

Any suggestions are very much appreciated!

Comment: Would check that the permissions for the snap are open.  Snaps usually have permissions that stop them from accessing other drives(USBs, other HDs, printers).  A simple first idea.

Comment: How do I check these permissions on snaps? How can I check them for TVHeadend?
Btw: if there aren't any entries in /dev/dvb then TVHeadend won't recognize the device

Comment: Try not to use snaps to much myself, but I think if you open the software store and click on tvheadend, it should open up a page with permissions icon near the top, along with launch, remove, icons.  At least it did when I tried it with the snap store, only snap I found with a very fast search.  Might be another problem, but this is fast and easy check first.

Comment: Permissions for snaps where already enabled

Comment: dmesg output after plugin
[  336.522408] usb 1-2: new high-speed USB device number 4 using xhci_hcd
[  336.675189] usb 1-2: New USB device found, idVendor=1d19, idProduct=0100, bcdDevice= 1.00
[  336.675195] usb 1-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[  336.675197] usb 1-2: Product: TS Aggregator
[  336.675199] usb 1-2: Manufacturer: ITE Tech., Inc.
[  336.675201] usb 1-2: SerialNumber: AF0102020700001

Comment: [  336.677603] dvb_usb_af9035 1-2:1.0: prechip_version=83 chip_version=01 chip_type=9306
[  336.677973] usb 1-2: dvb_usb_v2: found a 'Logilink VG0022A' in cold state
[  336.677998] usb 1-2: Direct firmware load for dvb-usb-it9303-01.fw failed with error -2
**bold [  336.678001] usb 1-2: dvb_usb_v2: Did not find the firmware file 'dvb-usb-it9303-01.fw' (status -2). You can use <kernel_dir>/scripts/get_dvb_firmware to get the firmware** 
[  336.678008] dvb_usb_af9035: probe of 1-2:1.0 failed with error -2
[  338.117455] kauditd_printk_skb: 487 callbacks suppressed

Comment: Device should be equivalent to Logilink VG0022A using firmware dvb-usb-it9303-01.fw